# How to solve ngOnInit Async Angular Issue?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I need the initialize form function to always be called after the contracts list is set, normally in react I would just re-render the component using a UseEffect with a callback to contracts, how would I make sure initializeForm() is called after contracts is set consistently? Right now sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.appContext = this.appContext;
    this.teamQueueService.GetContracts().subscribe(res => {
      this.contracts = res.userContractList;
      this.initializeForm();
    });
  }

  // Filter Validations
  get advanceSearchForm() {
    return this.searchForm.controls;
  }

  //#region Validation Functions
  initializeForm(): void {
    this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
      facilityName: ['', [Validators.maxLength(300), Validators.minLength(1)]],
      address: ['', [Validators.maxLength(300), Validators.minLength(1)]],
      city: ['', [Validators.maxLength(300), Validators.minLength(1), Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]*$')]],
      state: '',
      zipCode: ['', [Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(5)]],
      // tslint:disable-next-line:quotemark
      ccn: ['', [Validators.maxLength(6), Validators.minLength(6), Validators.pattern("^[a-zA-Z0-9 '-]+$")]],
      npi: ['', [Validators.maxLength(10), Validators.minLength(10), Validators.pattern('[0-9]\\d{9}')]],
      location: [5],
      distance: [0],
      disabled: true,
      contracted: false,
      participating: false,
      contract: this.contracts.find(c => c.contractId === this.facilityVerificationInfo.contractId).contractId,
      selectedContract: this.contracts.find(c => c.contractId === this.facilityVerificationInfo.contractId).contractId,
      careSetting: 0
    });
  }
```

Comment: By calling `initializeForm` in the `subscribe` you are ensuring that method is called after successful completion of observable (API call in your case maybe). There can be different issue if you are seeing any discrepancies in UI. Can you provide more background what do you exactly mean by saying "doesn't work"?

Comment: @ShreenilPatel sometimes when loading the page I get the error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contractId'), which makes me think that contracts is sometimes not populating in time as this is an inconsistent issue

Comment: How do you set `facilityVerificationInfo` ?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler passed from parent component using `@Input()`

Answer (score 0):

Your getter should return an optional/nullable :

```
get advanceSearchForm(): MyForm | undefined {
    return this.searchForm?.controls;
}
```

And it's up to you to handle that undefined in the template.

Comment: maybe I'm wrong as this is pretty new to me, but how would adding that to the getter allow me to ensure that this.InitializeForm() is ran after contracts are set?

Comment: You're already ensuring that by having `initializeForm` in the subscribe

Comment: is there another reason why sometimes I am getting error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contractId')? this code "works" but every now and then I get this error and it fails which makes me think it's an async issue

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this by storing function call in a ngOnChanges that looks for if facilityVerificationInfo exists.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeForm();
    this.service.appContext = this.appContext;
    this.teamQueueService.GetContracts().subscribe(res => {
      this.contracts = res.userContractList;
      // this.updateDefaultSelect();
    });
  }

  // Filter Validations
  get advanceSearchForm() {
    return this.searchForm.controls;
  }
  //set default contract and stuff
  updateDefaultSelect() {
    this.searchForm.controls['contract'].setValue(this.facilityVerificationInfo.contractId);
    this.searchForm.controls['selectedContract'].setValue(this.facilityVerificationInfo.contractId);
    const data = {
      source: 'default',
      value: this.facilityVerificationInfo.contractId
    };
    this.onContractChange(data);
  }

  // watches for facilityVerificationInfo Update
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (this.facilityVerificationInfo) {
      this.updateDefaultSelect();
    }
  }
```